# How to read the password for my profile?

Tags: login, password

I'd deleted all of the passwords from "Passwords and Keys" because when Ubuntu started up, there was an annoying program which required my password.
I wanted to install a new software, but unfortunately, my old password is not working because it is not exist anymore. I tried to read a "Login" password and a "Default keyring", but it isn't work either.
What should I do in this situation?

Comment: You deleted your password rather than delete the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these steps to set a new root password.

Steps:

1. Boot into recovery mode. Hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key or <kbd>esc</kbd> to see the grub menu while rebooting your system.
2. Select the **Advanced recovery mode** from the GRUB menu and then **recovery mode** on the next screen that appears.
3. On the next screen select **Drop to root shell prompt**
4. At the root shell prompt do the following:

   - Remount the root partition with "**read/write**" access with the following command:

     ```
     mount -rw -o remount /
     ```
   - Now set you **root user password** using this command. You will be prompted to enter it twice:

     ```
     passwd your_username
     ```
5. Exit the prompt by typing `exit` and hitting the return key.
6. On the next window select **Resume normal boot**