# Blank screen and blinking underscore after update to ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 from

Tags: boot, partial-upgrade

I was updating from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, when the update GUI showed a certain package from python3 could not be installed and the update failed. The message then showed restart required. After restarting it is just showing blank screen and blinking underscore.
I went into ubuntu recovery mode and run fsck and dpkg and then resumed, but the problem is still not solved

Comment: I do hope your backed up your system?

Comment: No I did not, but I have windows installed so major files are there.

Comment: ok then try the offered solution and let's hope it works

Comment: I tried but it is saying incorrect login despite giving the correct password several times

Comment: You may have to use a live system to set a new password then repeat the steps you just tried ... do you know how to do that?

Comment: No, could you help me do that?

Comment: Use this solution to do that: https://askubuntu.com/a/1269532/459561

Comment: Hey George, thanks man. The problem is solved now. I can access my system. I will be forever indebted to you